# Why is there a daily rep limit?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I'm relatively new to this community, but i really like discussing things here and sharing knowledge. Because of my activity, my rep skyrocketed ever since i came here. I just earned the Mortarboard badge because i earned 208 rep in one day. Cool and all, but i'm wondering what happens to that rep. Is it added the next day, or does it get thrown away? And why is here a limit, what is wrong with earning more than 200 rep a day? IMO it only discourages users to give more useful answers for that day when their daily limit is reached, and it does not have an strong advantage. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: I can see on the main site that you just got your Mortarboard badge for hitting the daily limit for the first time. Congrats on that, now you can aim for that silver badge we have for hitting the daily limit 50 times. It's called 'Epic' for a reason. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Appreciate your contributions so far :)

Comment: @tlhIngan Hahah 50 times, what the heck, that stands for some serious hardcore dedication! Way to go i guess...

Comment: There are StackOverflow users who hit the rep cap almost completely from upvotes on answers they've left several years ago. Let me introduce you to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=summary).

Comment: @Ellesedil Holy shite, i didn't even hold such a rank for possible... Is there even anything else that guy does in his life haha

Comment: @Bart He still leaves great answers and comments, but the vast majority of the upvotes he gets nowadays are on old answers for some more basic questions that sees a lot of traffic still.

Comment: @Ellesedil Yeah, the frequently asked question are answered already by those kind of guys, so it'd be rather hard to pull off such a trick again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

Just so we're clear, the daily rep limit isn't limited to this community. All StackExchange sites have the same limit.

In terms of why have such a limit at all, you've already pointed out some of the frustrations. On the other hand, a limit like this does reduce the possibility of rep spam or sock puppets. It's not easy to scam up a bunch of fake upvotes in order to raise a user account up to a crazy level in a short time. Instead, if you want a high rep, just keep participating. If you keep hitting the rep cap everyday, your total will go up faster than you expect.

In the end, this is a community. I don't come here for the points (which is one of the reasons that my rep has tapered off). I'm here for the people.

Comment: So the main goal is to prevent users from helping each other bump up each others rep, where the reason for upvoting is getting each other more rep? Sounds like a valid reason, but do these pathetic things really happen? As a side note, of course i'm not here for the rep, it doesn't get me anything but a feeling of appreciation.

Comment: @Bart the reason for upvoting is to help people find answers to their problems. The rep is a minor but appreciated reward for helping out.

Comment: Upvoting is how the community rates each question and answer so that better questions and answers are listed first.

Comment: And there is a daily limit on upvotes too :)

Comment: Might want to add too that if a question ends up on the HNQ list, an early answer can accumulate a massive amount of upvotes. I've had this happen to me on occasion; by answering early, getting a handful of upvotes to float my answer to first or second place, then the question hits the HNQ list and things really take off. If there was no daily rep cap, especially on beta sites where you aren't particularly familiar with the community standards, this could easily earn you a *lot* of privileges that you don't know how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Bob Cross has a very good answer on the individual side.

Another way to look at the daily rep limit is to avoid having the one user jump on every single question like a litigation lawyer on a Ford Pinto. Once a question has a good answer, what's the point of providing another lesser answer? The daily rep limit is one way to make sure we get answers from more people, gives more people a chance to chime in.

That being said, Paulster2's 70,000 rep at 200 per day looks even more impressive now, doesn't it?

Comment: More like a BUNCH of days with 10-50 points each day ... Maxing out your rep everyday would be a lot of work. I've only 71 days in the time I've been on here where I've maxed out my rep. Most of those days came in the past 10 months (probably 65 of them at a guess).

Comment: So to give others a chance to shine. That's a good legitimate reason i think. Still is a way of discouraging people that reached that limit, but for good reason. Offering room to others so the community can grow, which is an essential part of staying a healthy community. If only this community could reach the size of Stack Overflow...